# Had to install an earlier version of node.js and now none of the npm commands work

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I installed node.js to use my companies' packages. The node and npm commands were working fine, then a colleague mentioned I'd have to use an earlier version of node (Node v14.21.3 LTS) I uninstalled the current version of node and installed the previous version however now none of the npm commands work (including npm install) I get the following error:

```
`C:\Users\f.giovannini>npm install -g npm
C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\es6\validate-engines.js:31
    throw err
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'timers/promises'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\agent\lib\util.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\agent\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\remote.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\cache\entry.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\cache\index.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\fetch.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\make-fetch-happen\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-registry-fetch\lib\index.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\replace-info.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-message.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\exit-handler.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli-entry.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:774:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:107:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\f.giovannini\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\agent\lib\util.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1143:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:819:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1003:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\@npmcli\\agent\\lib\\util.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\@npmcli\\agent\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\make-fetch-happen\\lib\\remote.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\make-fetch-happen\\lib\\cache\\entry.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\make-fetch-happen\\lib\\cache\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\make-fetch-happen\\lib\\fetch.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\make-fetch-happen\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npm-registry-fetch\\lib\\index.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\replace-info.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\error-message.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\utils\\exit-handler.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli-entry.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\lib\\cli.js',
    'C:\\Users\\f.giovannini\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js'
  ]
}
`
```

I've seen other solutions to circumvent this problem suggest installing a newer version of node however I need to use the old one to be in line with my company.

I've reinstalled node.js a few times and checked the integrity of the install but it's all fine. I think maybe my version of npm isn't compatible with this version of node?

Turns out I still had some node files installed on my computer in appdata which is why npm was trying to run programs it didn't have access to. Thought I'd deleted everything through revo unistaller but it wasn't the case.

Comment: The promises API was new in Node v15: https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers-promises-api. You need to ensure your npm and Node versions are compatible with each other.

Comment: The `timers/promises` module requires v16 (it was under an experimental flag in v15).

Comment: And to be clear this has nothing to do with `npm`. Your code was written for a later version of Node.

Comment: use nvm, it allows each project to have different node version with the .npmrc file

Comment: @Lk77 that is true, though it should be noted that for production deployments a lot of people would shy away from those version managers (`n` and `nvm`) for security reasons.

Comment: Node 14 was a LTS release but it is *so old* that security support has ended. Your company should migrate ASAP.

Comment: `npm install -g npm` will install the latest npm. Maybe try `npm install -g npm@6` (which is the npm version that shipped with node 14)

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using nvm in order to easily switch between node versions.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on windows

Comment: You can use wsl2 for that then, i'm on windows and i'm running commands inside the ubuntu subsystem. Everything works seamlessly, my ide even use the wsl2 cli automatically it's convenient.